# how do I ignore NA when I make logical indexing in R?

Tags: r

```
n = c(1, 3, NA) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
k = df$n >= 2
df2 <- df[k,]
```

I want to find n is larger than 2. so I made k. If I run it:

```
.   n    s     b
2   3   bb   FALSE
NA NA   NA     NA
```

The result is above:
In this situation, I want to see a result without NA:
what should I do?

Comment: Use `k <- which(df$n >= 2)`

Comment: Fyi, some alternative interfaces (with packages data.table or dplyr) would ignore the NAs here.

Comment: Even in base, `subset(df, n >= 2)` doesn't include the `NA` row.